# How to inspect a Corona CAR file?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

A customer has supplied us with a corona CAR file. What command line tools (if any) are available to inspect its contents? Its a 'Corona ARchive' containing other files clearly, however it's neither in ZIP or a TAR format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .CAR file is not meant to be unpacked for inspection.  Its a proprietary format. I'm unware of any command line tools to unpack it.  Why does your customer need this?